# Два <textarea>. Первый показывает содержимое txt-файла, второй - этот же txt-файл обработанный. Изменения вручную первого мгновенно влияют на второй

Tags: javascript, html

На странице имеются несколько элементов: `div.list`, `textarea.out`. `div.list` каждую секунду обновляется и ajax-ом выводит список txt-файлов на сервере. При нажатии на любой элемент списка (читай: на название txt-файла) содержимое файла обрабатывается на стороне сервера и ajax-ом результат вставляется в textarea.out. То есть, событие `onclick` передает php название файла в json, далее php-функция `file($txt)` читает файл построчно. Но тут мне пришла в голову идея добавить элемент `textarea.in`. Теперь логика должна следующей. Я нажимаю на название файла, в `textarea.in` выводится содержимое txt-файла, а в `textarea.out` уже результат обработанного на сервере txt-файла.

Но это только пол-картины. К примеру, я вручную дописываю пару слов в `textarea.in`, и мгновенно вижу измененный результат в `textarea.out`. Отдает реактивностью. Но я пока только изучаю js и до vue пока не дошел.

Вопрос такой. Как при изменении `textarea.in` (именно не событиями onchange или там oninput, а если пришел ответ от сервера и text_in.value = xhr.response) отправлять ajax и получить ответ в textarea.out? textarea.in и text_in одно и то же. `text_in = document.querySelector('textarea.in');` Может get/set или что-то в этом духе? То есть, получается нужна функция, которая реагирует не на изменение text_in, а на изменение text_in.value...

Comment: Ну так это именно через oninput и делается. Упомянутый вами Vue тоже использует oninput

Comment: Но фразу "если пришел ответ от сервера и text_in.value = xhr.response" я не понял прям совсем

Comment: @andreymal, насчет фразы. Понимаете, когда мы нажимаем на название файла, мы ajax-ом отправляем серверу данные. Он отдает ответ в виде содержимого txt-файла и этот ответ мы записываем в textarea.in. Мы таким образом читаем файлы до обработки, чтобы видеть что обрабатывается.

Comment: Если вы хотите отправить ajax-запрос после строчки text_in.value = xhr.response, то что мешает просто взять и написать код отправки ajax-запроса после этой строчки?

Comment: Может вы и правы. Я начал, наверное, не с той стороны. Мне было интересно, как сделать через изменение value...

Comment: Скорее всего никак; насколько мне известно, браузер никак не уведомляет о том, что value был изменен скриптом (есть только oninput на случай ввода пользователем). Тот же Vue тоже игнорирует изменение value напрямую; все изменения Vue требует проводить через себя, иначе он их не сможет заметить и обработать

Answer (score 1):

Много текста вы написали, давайте кратко: есть `textarea`, значение в нем можно изменить несколькими способами и нам нужно как-то отслеживать эти изменения.

Тогда можно просто создать метод, с помощью которого мы будем устанавливать значение в `textarea`. Почти то же самое, что и ваш `get/set`.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('txt-in');

function createUpdatableTextarea(element) {
  // Наш метод по обновлению элемента
  element.update = function (value) {
    this.value = value;

    /**
    * А теперь самое важное, будем вызывать кастомное событие,
    * на которое можно подписаться. Тем самым 'скроем' всю внутреннию кухню
    * оставив одно событие.
    */

    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('update', {detail: this.value}));
  }
  
  // Сами подписываемся, например на oninput
  element.oninput = function (e) {
    this.update(e.target.value); // используем нашу функцию
  }
  
  return element;
}


// А теперь rock-n-roll!
const textarea = createUpdatableTextarea(document.getElementById('txt-in'));
const btnRand = document.getElementById('btn-rand');
const out = document.getElementById('txt-out');

btnRand.addEventListener('click', function () {
  // Обновляем значение через метод update
  textarea.update(Math.random());
});

textarea.addEventListener('update', ({detail}) => {
  out.value = detail;
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='txt-in'></textarea>
<textarea id='txt-out'></textarea>
<br>
<button id='btn-rand'>Добавить число</button>
```

Comment: Нужно немного времени, чтобы подробно изучить Ваш ответ. Спасибо! P.S. После php js кажется таким, мягко говоря, странным...

Comment: По-моему это всё тотальный оверкилл, я бы просто завёл `function update(newValue)` и просто запускал бы бы внутри всё что нужно вместе с ajax-запросами и прочим

Comment: @andreymal ну у меня суть примерно такая же

Comment: @ThisMan суть такая же, но с тотальными переусложнениями :)

Comment: @andreymal у меня метод, у вас функция. Разницы кажется не так уж и много. В данном случае `createUpdatableTextarea` вообще может классом быть, что бы создавать несколько экземпляров. Намеки на масштабирование

Comment: @ThisMan, update - это встроенная функция js?

Comment: @forever_young нет, мы ее сами объявили